# Vertically stack components of a cell in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell `A` in Matlab composed by sub-arrays with different number of rows but same number of columns, e.g. `A={[1 2 3; 4 5 6] [7 8 9] [10 11 12; 13 14 15; 16 17 18]}`. Without using loops, I want to vertically stack each sub-array in a matrix `B`. In the example,

```
B=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15; 16 17 18]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [vertcat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) to concatenate subcells vertically:

```
B = vertcat(A{:})

B =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
```